# How do I get data from enums in rust?

Tags: rust, enums, match

I am learning rust and have come across enums. I understand why they might be useful for organising variables. It is also far more difficult to access data in said enums. My question comes down to this: why do people use enums and is there an easy way to retrieve the data from them?

My current solution to the latter is to use a match statement:

```
enum Breakfast {
    Toast(String),
}

fn main() {
    let breakfast = Breakfast::Toast(String::from("Buttered"));

    match breakfast {
        Breakfast::Toast(t) => println!("{}",t),
        _ => panic!("I'm Hungry!"), 
    }
}
```

This is a very inefficient, are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: [Enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type); _Enum is a data type consisting of a set of named values called elements_. Enum is not specific to the Rust-lang but It has more features, you can check this [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) for more information. It is usually used to manage static set of variants for a specific context. For example if you are creating a menu for `Breakfast` it might not be a good idea since menu items can change continuously, but Meal { Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner } could be a good fit to express this context in your code.

Comment: _This is a very inefficient, are there any other ways to do this_ What makes you think it is inefficient? What you are doing is called [destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring.html) in Rust.

Comment: @ Ömer Erden Say I wanted to do a whole list of functions with the data in toast. I would have to write all of them within the match function to do this.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand why they might be useful for organising variables.

I've got no idea what that means.

> My question comes down to this: why do people use enums

Because they allow making invalid states unrepresentable<sup>1</sup>: enums allow *exclusive* representations.

> and is there an easy way to retrieve the data from them?

`match`, `if let`, utility functions which bundle the access or even provides higher-level operations on them.

Your example is too detached from any information to make any judgement upon it (e.g. on whether you're misusing enums) aside from "the compiler literally tells you that the `_` case is useless".

But for instance the `Option` and `Result` types are enums. Because an `Option` is *either* `Some` or `None`, and a `Result` is *either* `Ok` or `Err`. Enums allow this information to be part of the typesystem, and thus the compiler to assist with checking it.

---

1: though a common issue is what states are actually invalid, there are domains where it's not clear cut, the validity of a given datum can even vary based on domain!

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous answer misinterpreted your question.

A simple let statement can also destructure the enum. However usually there is more than one enum variant.

```
enum Breakfast {
    Toast(String),
}

fn main() {
    let breakfast = Breakfast::Toast(String::from("Buttered"));

    let Breakfast::Toast(t) = breakfast;

    println!("{}", t);
}

enum Breakfast {
    Toast(String),
    Eggs(String)
}

fn main() {
    let breakfast = Breakfast::Toast(String::from("Buttered"));
    let _breakfast2 = Breakfast::Eggs(String::from("Over Easy"));

    if let Breakfast::Toast(t) = breakfast {
        println!("{}", t);
    } ;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you actually want the enum to be 'MenuItem' as opposed to 'Breakfast'. Then 'Breakfast' would be some sort of container, say a vec[], of 'MenuItems'. And each item might have its own attribute data. Say 'buttered' 'over-easy' etc.